# Is there any Java support for JSPON serialization with references?

Tags: java, json, jsonserializer

I'm looking for a Java JSPON serializer that can handle references according to the [JSPON  specification.](http://www.jspon.org/)

Are there any available that can do this currently? Or is there any way to modify an existing serializer to handle object refs with the $ref notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

If you are interested in an object-JSON binding approach, below is how it could be done using MOXy.  The example below is based on the example one from the JSPON Core Spec:

- http://www.jspon.org/JSPON_Core_Spec.htm

**Parent**

The `Parent` class is the domain object that corresponds to the root of the JSON message.  It has two fields that are of type `Child`.

```
package forum9862100;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Parent {

    protected Child field1;
    protected Child field2;

}
```

**Child**

The `Child` class may be referenced by its key. We will handle this use case with an `XmlAdapter`. We link to an `XmlAdapter` via the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation.

```
package forum9862100;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ChildAdapter.class)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Child {

    protected String id;
    protected String foo;
    protected Integer bar;

}
```

**ChildAdapter**

Below is the implementation of the `XmlAdapter`.  This `XmlAdapter` is stateful which means we will need to set an instance on the `Marshaller` and `Unmarshaller`.

```
package forum9862100;

import java.util.*;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class ChildAdapter extends XmlAdapter<ChildAdapter.AdaptedChild, Child>{

    private List<Child> childList = new ArrayList<Child>();
    private Map<String, Child> childMap = new HashMap<String, Child>();

    public static class AdaptedChild extends Child {
        @XmlElement(name="$ref")
        public String reference;
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedChild marshal(Child child) throws Exception {
        AdaptedChild adaptedChild = new AdaptedChild();
        if(childList.contains(child)) {
            adaptedChild.reference = child.id;
        } else {
            adaptedChild.id = child.id;
            adaptedChild.foo = child.foo;
            adaptedChild.bar = child.bar;
            childList.add(child);
        }
        return adaptedChild;
    }

    @Override
    public Child unmarshal(AdaptedChild adaptedChild) throws Exception {
        Child child = childMap.get(adaptedChild.reference);
        if(null == child) {
            child = new Child();
            child.id = adaptedChild.id;
            child.foo = adaptedChild.foo;
            child.bar = adaptedChild.bar;
            childMap.put(child.id, child);
        }
        return child;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

The code below demonstrates how to specify a stateful `XmlAdapter` on the `Marshaller` and `Unmarshaller`:

```
package forum9862100;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class);

        StreamSource json = new StreamSource(new File("src/forum9862100/input.json"));
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        unmarshaller.setAdapter(new ChildAdapter());
        Parent parent = (Parent) unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Parent.class).getValue();

        System.out.println(parent.field1 == parent.field2);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        marshaller.setAdapter(new ChildAdapter());
        marshaller.marshal(parent, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.  Note how the two instances of `Child` pass the identity test.

```
true
{
   "field1" : {
      "id" : "2",
      "foo" : "val",
      "bar" : 4
   },
   "field2" : {
      "$ref" : "2"
   }}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mixing-nesting-and-references-with.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of the many Object to JSon serialization libraries. Many of the libraries are extensible, but I suspect adding references could get complicated unless you make some pragmatic choices as to when to use these.